# Rendering a Custom Model ( From Photoshop 3D Export )

Tags: ios, opengl-es, photoshop, glkit

I've been trying for most of the day to get a custom object object into iOS for rendering in OpenGL ES or GLKit.

From photoshop I can export in the following formats: Collada, Flash 3D, Google Earth 4 KMZ, U3D and Wavefront|OBJ.

My first question is, which of the formats that Photoshop can export is most compatible with getting my model into iOS. I've been trying OBJ for most of the day, but the expectation is that I would need to basically "roll" my own OBJ loader, most of the ones on the internet already developed and in various Stackoverflow answers no longer function or render the textures of my object.

Any suggestions for how I can move this forward. I'm well motivated to learn, but I just need a push in the right direction.

Comment: What problem do you have in using other obj loaders?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done this for iOS, but I've written an OpenGL .obj loader a few times for school projects, it's not hard assuming you have good knowledge of how OpenGL works.

With quick searching, I found these resources. First is an open source OBJ loader, that might work for you (don't know if you tried this already):
http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.fi/2009/03/wavefront-obj-loader-open-sourced-to.html

Another could be the PowerVR POD loader found in the open source iSGL3D framework. I don't know anything about this format, but you should be able to convert your models using PVRGeoPODGUI or Collada2pod tools. I don't know how good the iSGL3D framework is, though.

There's also cocos3d that's not released yet, but already usable: http://brenwill.com/cocos3d. They promise mesh loading from multiple formats, including Blender, 3DS Max and Collada. This might be your best bet, actually.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the alternative suggestions. I have played around with the Wavefront Obj Loader quite a bit, unfortunately Photoshop exports only UV Textures and apparently his implementation does not work well with that. Your other suggestions should be interesting to check out, thank you again!